# How has Bisquick's “original” recipe changed over time?

Tags: pancakes, history

I noticed that the “original recipe” Bisquick in my mother's fridge a) contains sugar, b) does not list hydrogenated oils, and c) does not say to keep refrigerated. This is not consistent with our collective memories. I did some googling and found some information on various changes over time, such as replacing lard with hydrogenated oils, but nothing like a definitive timeline, and no reliable-looking sources or citations.

I am also aware that there have been other Bisquick products, such as a “Heart Smart” version with no trans fats, but I'm mostly interested in how the composition of the “original”-branded version has changed.

Does anyone know of any authoritative sources on this?

Comment: Good luck.  There really aren't authoritative sources for changes to a product over time if the manufacturer doesn't share them.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Not that it's necessarily an easy route, but I wonder if manufacturers' catalogues or such have to go to a library of record, in countries that have them.

Comment: @FuzzyChef in the good(?) old days of the internet there would have been a GeoCities page where someone collected vintage Bisquick labels.  For every subject there's a useful nerd.

Comment: @dbmag9 I suppose that theoretically you could file a request with the FDA.

Comment: @ChrisH I expect that there still is, it's just that Google doesn't index it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As I love Bisquick, you question made me do a little search and ended up on generalmills https://www.generalmills.com/news/stories/how-bisquick-got-its-start page.

There is a mention of the original recipe there and some old newspaper scan (too small for me to read, dont wear the glasses:-)

Hope it helps

Comment: That’s an ad for the product. It doesn’t include a recipe.